# Creación de trigger para restar Stock

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

La estructura de la base de datos es la siguiente:
[image: Estructura de la base de datos]

Se pide crear un trigger que al crear un pedido descuente el número de unidades del pedido del stock de la tabla artículos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER restar_stock 
    AFTER INSERT ON pedidos
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE articulos NATURAL JOIN pedidos
    SET articulos.stock = articulos.stock - pedidos.unidades;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

El código como lo he elaborado no funciona, ya que actualiza el campo "stock" de todos los registros que hay en la tabla.

Además, debe ejecutarse este trigger cuando llame a este proceso almacenado:

```
DELIMITER $
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS nuevopedido $
CREATE PROCEDURE nuevopedido(IN articulo INT(11), IN cliente INT(11), IN unidades INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES (null, articulo, cliente, unidades, 0, NOW());
END $
DELIMITER ;

call (1,1,5)
```

(Por ejemplo).

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, es porque debes agregar la condición `WHERE articulo_id`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar la condición WHERE para que descuente sólo el artículo que necesitas. Bajo tu actual código actualiza todos los registros de la tabla.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER restar_stock 
    AFTER INSERT ON pedidos
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE articuloId integer;
    DECLARE UNPedido integer;
    UPDATE articulos
    SET stock = stock - UNPedido
    WHERE articulo_id = articuloId
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Es necesario el join? no estan los datos nuevos ya dentro del Trigger, al ser un after insert?

Comment: Tienes razón, se podría quitar el `join` declarando la cantidad a descontar del stock.

Comment: Modifica el trigger para que quede bien ;)

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la observación

Comment: Disculpa, no me termina de funcionar ese código, ahora no me resta en ningún registro.

Comment: @StakerBro ¿estás enviando los parámetros UNPedido y articuloId ?

Comment: Disculpa, se me olvidó comentar algo. Tengo un proceso almacenado que es el siguiente       DELIMITER $
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS nuevopedido $
CREATE PROCEDURE nuevopedido(IN articulo INT(11), IN cliente INT(11), IN unidades INT(11))
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES (null, articulo, cliente, unidades, 0, NOW());
END $
DELIMITER ;           La cuestión es que al ejecutar este proceso almacenado con call (1,1,20) por ejemplo, tiene que actualizarse el stock. Disculpa si no fui claro en la explicación anterior.

Comment: Pero esto es un trigger, no un SP.. no se le envian parametros.. ya sabe cuales son...

Comment: He modificado el problema que tengo añadiendo más detalles en el post. Gracias.

Comment: @StakerBro y si haces el `UPDATE` del stock dentro del SP nuevopedido

Comment: Es para un ejercicio y me pide estrictamente que lo haga en un trigger..

Comment: @StakerBro según tu antepenúltima respuesta _"He modificado el problema que tengo añadiendo más detalles en el post. Gracias"_ entiendo que ya está solucionado. Espero que nuestra ayuda te haya servido. Y recuerda que puedes **Votar** o **Aceptar** la pregunta según este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: No me refiero a que esté solucionado, me refiero a que he añadido más contenido acerca del error que tengo (añadiendo que el trigger debería ejecutarse al llamar al proceso almacenado y  no con parámetros). No está solucionado.